# Purposefully avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, string

`string.split("\n")[1]` always gives me a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Is there a way to prevent that? Does a real code like the following exist?

```
if(!ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
    string.split("\n")[1]
```

Comment: are you looking for `String[] splitted = string.split("\n"); if (splitted.length > 1) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.split("\n")` returns a `String` array.
`string.split("\n")[1]` assumes that the return value is an array that has at least two elements.
`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` indicates that the array has **less than two elements**.

If you want to prevent getting that exception, you need check the length of the array.  Something like...

```
String[] parts = string.split("\n");
if (parts.length > 1) {
    System.out.println(parts[1]);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Less than 2 elements.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first element of an array is at index 0.  Do not assume that there are always two elements.  The last index in an array has an index of (length - 1).

Answer (score 0):

Indexing starts with 0, so by indexing with 1 you are trying to get the second element of the array which is in your case a potentiel second line of a text. You are having such error because you may have no line break in your string, to avoid such exception you can either use a try catch block (I don't like this method in your case) or just check if there is a line break in your string, you can do it like this:

```
if(yourString.contains("\n")){
    //split your string and do the work
}
```

or even by checking the length of the parts due to split:

```
String[] parts = yourString.split("\n");
if(parts.length>=2){
    //do the work
}
```

If you want to use the try-catch block:

```
try {
    String thisPart = yourString.split("\n")[1];
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //  Handle the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException case
}
//  continue your work
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use **try-catch** to avoid getting this message:

```
try{
     string.split("\n")[1];
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
      //here for example you can 
      //print an error message
}
```